# ES6 Module Loader from String Literal - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

With the use of **ES6 Module Loader Polyfill**, I've found that given a JavaScript file (`module1.js`):

```
export class q {
   constructor() {
      console.log('this is an es6 class!');
   }
}
```

One can *import* the mentioned module with the following code:

```
<script>
  System.import('mymodule').then(function(m) {
    new m.q();
  });
</script>
```

My question is: I need to do this (almost) very same thing but instead of *importing* a file, use a `String` literal. For example:

```
<script>
  module = `   
    export class q {
      constructor() {
         console.log('this is an es6 class!');
      }
    }
  `;
  System.import(module).then(function(m) { // not possible
    new m.q();
  });
</script>
```

The reason of this, is because the Angular app receives the module as a response from a `HttpRequest` call embedded in a Json response like this:

```
{
    "module": "export class q {
       constructor() {
          console.log('this is an es6 class!');
       }
    }"
}
```

Comment: I'm sure that module loader polyfill has a way to declare a module. Did you check its docs?

Comment: @Bergi What exactly do you mean by *"declare a module"*? The module needs to be dynamic. Yes, I checked its docs but it seems to only import files. I could get in its source and make it work to accept a `String` literal directly instead of downloading a file, but there must be a way to do it, it's difficult to believe that this simple (and obvious) feature does not exists.